# Can't login Google Drive app Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

I installed Google Drive on my fathers Assus Eee PC running Windows 7. The installation worked fine but when I tried to login afterwards for some reason the html the Drive app uses is opened in notepad and not in the application.

Does anybody know what's causing this behaviour? I know this isn't actual related to Google Drive. I've seen it before on the same pc with other applications.

Edit:
As you can see on the picture below, the white screen in the back is the Google Drive App. In the front you'll see the content that should be shown opened in Notepad.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1849848/login.png]

Comment: A screenshot is worth a thousand words.

Comment: have you tried going to "Default Programs" and resetting Internet Explorer to have all its defaults?